# Find Data Using Laravel Framework

Tags: laravel

I want match data from  "jobTable" based on job id then i got 5 data within this 5 data i have userId i want to show data from "userTable" based on userID. Then i will catch it on variable and i want to show it on my view then i will show it using loop.

If i do this below code it shows all data from my userTable not show based on matched JobID base UserId Details.

```
public function applyUser($jobId){

    $applyUsers=ApplyInfo::where('job_id', $jobId)->get();
    //5 rows found, with in this 5 rows everybody has userId  I want to show data from user table based on this found userId and pass value a variable then i will loop it on view page.

   foreach ($applyUsers as $applyUser){

     $applyUsersDtials=Employee::find($applyUser->user_id)->get();

   }

    return view('front.user.apply-user-details', ['applyUsersDtials'=>$applyUsersDtials]);
}

//when i do that that time show all data based on my user table not show based on my JobId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your code `$applyUsersDtials` is a variable it should be an array. Next when you need to find a single row you just need to use `find()`. Try this-

```
public function applyUser($jobId){

    $applyUsers = ApplyInfo::where('job_id', $jobId)->get();

    $applyUsersDtials = [];

    foreach ($applyUsers as $applyUser){
        $applyUsersDtials[] = Employee::find($applyUser->user_id);
    }

    return view('front.user.apply-user-details',
                ['applyUsersDtials' => $applyUsersDtials]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro @Risul Islam its working right now. Main point is I need declare the veritable as a array.